# Mapbox navigation finish route

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox

I use Mapbox Navigation turn-by-turn UI and want to do something after finish route. I can't find function for this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [`ProgressChangeListener`](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/route-progress/#on-progress-change)

```
NavigationViewOptions.Builder options = NavigationViewOptions.builder();
options.progressChangeListener(new ProgressChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
    if (routeProgress.currentState().equals(RouteProgressState.ROUTE_ARRIVED)) {
      // Execute arrival logic
    }
  }
});
```